# How to create some tags under a special category?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I saw someone could create tags which are classifies into different folders in some tools like sourcetree.

I am wondering how to create the tags with folders

folder1,tag1,tag2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag folders don't exists in `git`. However, some tools use the convention to consider whatever is before a `/` in the reference name as a folder or path. This applies to references in general, therefore tags and branches.

You can use:

```
$ git tag folder1/tag1
```

to create a "`tag1` with `folder1`".

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended to use annotated tag instead of regular tag.

You simply add the `-a` as flag to the tag and the tag will include the same metadata as in commit. (committer, author, date, message etc)

[image]